# How to reduce app size by removing lib folder

Tags: android, apk, proguard

So after building my release apk, I see that the size of the app is much higher than expected even though proguard/R8 is enabled. When analyzed with apk analyzer I see that most of the size comes from 'lib' folder and has got no part in my coding (hope its some part of support library for all API levels). So is there a way to remove that folder and is it ok to do so. My app uses the minimum required API level 24 and target 28.

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
```

Comment: The `lib/` folder should contain native binaries that are coming from one of your dependencies. If you do not want those native binaries, remove the dependency.

Comment: you can go with app bundle if you want to release it on play store.

Comment: I guess it's kinda a stupid question but is there any specific way to check which dependency is producing them.